# Two acceptors over same socket

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Can two acceptors async_accept on one socket? I want to listen on both ipv4 & ipv6.

In other words, is following usage valid?

```
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

boost::asio::io_service io_service;

tcp::acceptor a4(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port_));
tcp::acceptor a6(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v6(), port_));
tcp::socket s(io_service);

a4.async_accept(s, std::bind(handle_connection, s, std::placeholders::_1);
a6.async_accept(s, std::bind(handle_connection, s, std::placeholders::_1);
```

Let's ignore code around it, what I do with socket later and where I call io_service.run() is not really important (or is it?).

Thanks for help & advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as I know a call to io_service.run() is obligatory, otherwise there will not happen that much.... [Look up the examples Here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html)

Setup a socket for each connection ([Here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/async_accept/overload1.html)), otherwise you will override previous connection data created by `async_accept()`

> This function is used to asynchronously accept a new connection into a
>   socket...

pay attention to the phrasing "into a socket"

Comment: "as far as I know a call to io_service.run() is obligatory" - I know, what I meant was that it's not relevant to my question where I call io_service.run.. Anyway I do call it

Answer (score 3):

It is best to use a `socket` per accept operation.  When two asynchronous accept operations attempt to use the same peer `socket`:

- If a single thread runs the `io_service` (i.e. implicit [strand](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html)) or the operations are invoked within an explicit strand, then the result is unspecified as the order in which the operations complete is unspecified.  The `socket` will be associated to the connection of the operation which completes first.  When the other operation completes, it will fail with `boost::asio::error::already_open` if `socket` is still associated with the other connection.
- If multiple threads run the `io_service` and the operations are not synchronized with a strand, then undefined behavior may be invoked, as `socket` is [not thread safe](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/socket.html#boost_asio.reference.ip__tcp.socket.thread_safety).